# Slim and Rails issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, slim-lang

Basically I am trying to get this output in Rails and Slim:

```
<a href="/some/link">my<strong>name</strong></a>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
= link_to 'my<strong>name</strong>', controller: :pages, action: :home
```

Obviously it outputs:

`my<strong>name</strong>` on the page instead of interpreting the strong tags. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Rails that the string is safe :

```
= link_to 'my<strong...>'.html_safe
```